# AOP cannot execute after jar package is introduced

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

**Spring Boot project**

Packaged JAR:

[image]

Added proxy:

[image]

Added Maven POM:

[image]

It can be used when the JAR package is not packaged.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Maybe you can try to translate your Chinese comments to English using Google Translate or a similar tool. Please also be advised to post some code, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), instead of screenshots on third-party websites. If you add screenshots in order to illustrate your prose and code, please add them inline using the editor here. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I just translated your Chinese text to English and in-lined the screenshots so they are visible. But please do what I said above and edit the question to become an MCVE.